# Firebase OTP Authentication returning web page to check for robot

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have implemented firebase mobile OTP authentication. Initially, the login was working perfectly fine. But now it is opening a new page to verify if I am a robot or not.
How to avoid such page

The app is right now in internal testing and we keep on testing it for 15v till now.

Is it due to the number of testing or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Auth Version and it will work well for you :)

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'